# Run a few command line commands from c++

Tags: c++, python, linux, command-line

I wrote a program in python that has the functionality of being able to find out file sizes, create directories, and move around as though i'm just in a regular shell. The porblem is that I need to be able to do this in c++.

Here's the python code that I need c++ functionality from:

```
os.chdir('r'+str(r)+'n'+str(n))
def build_path(newpath):
    if os.path.isdir(newpath):
        os.chdir(newpath)
    else:
        os.mkdir(newpath)
        os.chdir(newpath)
```

And also this piece:

```
if os.stat('data'+str(tick)).st_size > 2500000:
    heavyFile.close()
    tick+=1
    heavyFile=open('data'+str(tick),'w')
os.system('touch COMPLETED'+str(r)+str(n))
```

So basically I need to be able to make some directories, change into those directories, build files, but don't let them get much larger than 2.5 MB, and when they finally get over that size, create a new file that is incremented by one.

so the file tree ends up looking like:

r4n4/dir1/data0,data1,data2,etc
r4n4/dir2/data0,data1,data2,etc
and so on.

How can I do this in c++?
I know I can call system('command')
but I don't know how to get file size nicely using that and I'm just hoping for an easier way to do this.
Also, I do not have access to boost where I am running this program.

Comment: Essentially what you asking for here is how to manipulate and query the filesystem from C++, and not necessarily run command line commands from C++, although I can understand your line of thinking to get to your current title.  I would recommend changing your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stat()` in your code to get properties of filesystem objects. Here's an example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat buf;
stat(filename, &buf);

// If it's a regular file, print the size in bytes
if ((buf.st_mode & S_IFREG) == S_IFREG)
{
  off_t size = buf.st_size;
  fprintf(stdout, "%s is a regular file\n", filename);
  fprintf(stdout, "%s is a regular file: size %zd bytes\n", filename, size);
}
```

There are also macros within `stat.h` which make it a little easier to check if something is a regular file or whatever, instead of AND'ing multiple things as above.  For example, the S_ISREG macro will do the same thing as the code above:

```
if(S_ISREG(buf.st_mode))   /* stat.h macro, instead of AND'ing */
{
  fprintf(stdout, "%s is a regular file\n", filename);
}
```

The macro `S_ISDIR` would tell you if it's a directory. There are other macros like this.

You can do `man -s 2 stat` to see the man page for stat() and get more details.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out the boost::filesystem library. (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)  All three of your requests are covered in the tutorial.

Comment: I do not have access to boost where I am running this, else that would be a great solution.

Comment: You do not need access to boost where you run it, you just need it where you compile it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of system calls to achieve what you want.  If you are on Linux, check out the following man pages:

```
man 2 chdir
man 2 mkdir
man 2 stat
```

Comment: how do you get the output from stat back into your program?

Comment: The output of `stat(2)` will be in the parameter `struct stat * buf` which is the second parameter for `stat`.  You will pass that to `stat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just call your script from your c++ code with this command:

```
system ("python script.py");
```